# How to control the Microphone Boost in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, mixer, wasapi

I am trying to control the Microphone Boost (level/(un)mute) in Windows 7 using the MIXER API in a C/C++ application, but I do not get the controls for the same. Can it be done using WASAPI? Can somebody suggest any other API to control the Microphone Boost in Windows 7?

This is what I have written so far ...

```
const IID IID_IDeviceTopology = __uuidof(IDeviceTopology);
const IID IID_IPart = __uuidof(IPart);
const IID IID_IAudioAutoGainControl = __uuidof(IAudioAutoGainControl);

HRESULT hr = S_OK;
CoInitialize(NULL);

IMMDeviceEnumerator *deviceEnumerator = NULL;
hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (LPVOID *)&deviceEnumerator);

IMMDevice *pEndptDev = NULL;

hr = deviceEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eCapture, eConsole, &pEndptDev);
deviceEnumerator->Release();
deviceEnumerator = NULL;


IDeviceTopology *pDevTopoEndpt = NULL;
IConnector *pConnEndpt = NULL;
IConnector *pConnHWDev = NULL;
IPart *pPartConn = NULL;
IAudioAutoGainControl *pAGC = NULL;
IControlInterface *pControl = NULL;
UINT pCount = 0;
LPCGUID pIID = ;

// Get the endpoint device's IDeviceTopology interface.
hr = pEndptDev->Activate(IID_IDeviceTopology, CLSCTX_ALL, NULL, (void**)&pDevTopoEndpt);

// The device topology for an endpoint device always
// contains just one connector (connector number 0).
hr = pDevTopoEndpt->GetConnector(0, &pConnEndpt);

// Use the connector in the endpoint device to get the
// connector in the adapter device.
hr = pConnEndpt->GetConnectedTo(&pConnHWDev);

// Query the connector in the adapter device for
// its IPart interface.
hr = pConnHWDev->QueryInterface(IID_IPart, (void**)&pPartConn);

// Use the connector's IPart interface to get the
// IDeviceTopology interface for the adapter device.
hr = pPartConn->Activate(CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IAudioAutoGainControl, (void**)&pAGC);
hr = pPartConn->GetControlInterfaceCount(&pCount);
hr = pPartConn->GetControlInterface(pCount - 1, &pControl);
hr = pControl->GetIID((GUID *)pIID);

//BOOL bEnabled = false;
hr = pAGC->SetEnabled(true, pIID);
```

Answer (score 2):

WASAPI is the way to do this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370853%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Selbie. A hardware level AGC would be great if it worked. How can I use the IAudioAutoGainControl::SetEnabled function? I do not understand how to get the GUID? I have edited the question and am specifically concerned about how to get the GUID so as to SetEnable the AGC.