# Setting the Microphone Boost in Windows 7

Tags: c#, audio, mixer

I have been searching and scouring the web for help with setting audio properties from code. I have several systems in each of several locations that are regularly used to capture spoken audio through the microphone. To insure that the captured audio is sufficiently clear I need to be able to programmatically set things on startup, like microphone and speaker volumes, to prescribed values. For some of these systems I need to be able to set the Microphone Boost.

With XP I was able to use the AudioMixer library, however, this doesn't do everything on Win7 systems which is what I have now. I have looked at the CoreAudioApi library for the Master Volume but I can't find anything that shows how to set the Microphone Boost, which now shows as a slider/numeric control instead of a simple checkbox. All other information I have found is written in C++, to which I am a rank novice, and one of those examples left the impression that while Microphone Boost was found using IDeviceTopology, it couldn't be set.

Comment: If it's helpful at all, the microphone boost is a driver-specific feature.  It isn't something that will be available everywhere.  Also, I don't know the purpose of your software but if you plan to distribute it to others, be aware that many folks have set their microphone volumes already, and that controlling microphone boost may not be the best idea.

Comment: I realize that Mic Boost doesn't apply to every system. The utility is used totally in-house to check and set, if needed, certain audio settings on multiple differing systems to insure parity across the network. This is not a matter of individual preferences. Keep in mind this was previously done on the same systems with XP, They are now Win 7 which requires a different approach.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8905599/362536

Comment: To whomever voted to close this question as off-topic... it'd be best if you actually read the question before marking to close it.  This question is most certainly on-topic for Stack Overflow, and if you think otherwise you should read the "help" page again.

Comment: Thanks for teh referrel Brad but I have already looked at that. From what I've seen I need to use the IDeviceTopology but I haven't found a workable way in... Still looking.